# Locate certain words in notepad

Tags: python

my this program will locate the word "@@END DATA" in my notepad folder.

Problem: If my folder contain 2 "@@End DATA", It will only get the one that come first. How can i get the last "@@End DATA" that come last?? Just to return end number(Index)

```
def locateEndData(fileTitle):
try:
    filename = fileTitle.split()[-1]
    global end
    f = open(filename,"r")
    with open(filename) as myFile:
        for end, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if '@@END Data' in line:
                return end
    f.close()
```

File Name = C:/Users/zhenhui/Desktop/VSM/JDP2270-Hys-IP.VHD

```
fileTitle = C:/Users/zhenhui/Desktop/VSM/JDP2270-Hys-IP.VHD
locateEndData(fileTitle)
```

Comment: use yield instead of return, see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my `s.txt` looks like:

```
@@END Data
kdawg
@@END Data
```

Use regex:

```
import re

regex = "@@END Data"

def locateEndData(fileTitle):
    try:
        filename = fileTitle.split()[-1]
        with open(filename) as myFile:
            matches = [(m.start(0)+1, m.end(0)+1) for m in re.finditer(regex, myFile.read())]
        return matches[1] #To return the index of the last match
    except:
        print "sorry, dude..."

print locateEndData('s.txt')
```

output is in the form `(start,end)`:

```
[(1, 11), (18, 28)]
```

---

`(1, 11)` is for the first `@@END Data`

`(18, 28)` is for the second `@@END Data`

Comment: good heavens man, its like you can't help yourself from using the `global` statement.

Comment: It wasn't me, mate. It would take absolutely egregious code for my to downvote on of your answers.

Comment: @KDawG why is the value 17,27 it is totally out of range. Shouldn't it be 0 and 2

Comment: @ZhenHui actually there are two @@END Data sice you asked the index for the last @@END Data I made it print matches[1] BTW edited see now